# Reflection in C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, porting

I am currently porting a game from Cocos2d written in ObjectiveC to Cocos2d-x in C++. Now the objective C guys have used Reflection to populate modal classes from a json object. Is the same possible in C++ Can we use reflection in C++ ?

Kind Regards

Comment: No, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection

Comment: Btw, did these links not pop up when you were typing your question?

Comment: At least I have a proposal for it https://github.com/hun-nemethpeter/cpp-reflector-mini/blob/master/Proposal.md

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [C++ has no reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection).

The default solution is to register all the symbols that you need in an associative array, like [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/). [Here are examples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665423/minimal-reflection-in-c).